# how can i hide complete app (with sub-names) in magisk with sh command with sh

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh, adb

`magiskhide add <PKGNAME>`

`magiskhide add <PKGNAME> <subname>`

[image]

above command only hiding this

yes I can add pkg name and then these sub-names in command to hide rest options but do you know how can I hide complete app in 1 command if not then please tell me the way how can I copy these sub names (and what are they called) to use them in my command line